# Vite really slow

Tags: build, create-react-app, vite

I have been utilizing CRA (create-react-app) for my projects and have found it to be quite effective. However, I am considering switching to Vite. Unfortunately, I've noticed that when I make changes to the code, the loading and hot reloading of the application can take a significant amount of time, especially when using a browser with a heavy page.

Although I have assigned each role to a specific client app, I am still encountering the same problem.